# Can i delete folders and files in my Assembla account?

Tags: svn, version-control, assembla

I want to delete my folders and my files in Assembla SVN tab menu, but don't how to do it.
I use Assembla in free mode, need your help to do this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout the folders to your local machine and can delete from your working copy and commit the changes. Other option is `svn rm path/to/repo/folder`

Comment: So it can't from the assembla it self ya?, the other option command i never use that command, how to run that command ? in local pc or in assembla svn ? thanks

Comment: Deddy- I am not sure about the GUI option. Regarding the command, yes, you need to run it in your local machine only. Alternately I think you can drop a mail to support@assembla.com, they must be able to assist you in a better way. They have a very good support.

Comment: Ok, i will ask to Assembla support team, Thank Dipu